# SQL - select rows where the value from a column is not identical with the value from another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table similar to this:

| id | code_a | code_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_1 | 123 | 123 |
| id_2 | 234 | 234 |
| id_3 | 567 | 123 |
| id_4 | 987 | 987 |
| id_5 | 765 | 765 |

Does anybody know how to create a query that selects only the rows where the value from **code_a** is not equal to the value from **code_b**?

The result I'm expecting is:

| id | code_a | code_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id_3 | 567 | 123 |

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

```
select id, code_a, code_b
  from your_table
 where col_a <> col_b
```

?

UPD: As per Gordon Linoff's note the query will not return rows where one of cols (or both) are null. For this case you need to use a function like "nvl" or "ifnull" or "isnull" depending on which database are you running on

Comment: yup, thank you! I think I had a brain fart when thinking at the problem...

Comment: @drake10k . . . Just be careful if the columns can have `NULL` values.  This will never return rows where the values are `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff good point, thanks! I've updated the answer